# Where to put logic that is repeated amongst my Fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, design-patterns

I have a tab-based application with 5 tabs (`Fragments`). Each fragment is very similar in appearance and functionality. Where should I put this logic for these classes so that I am not repeating it in each Fragment?

Should I be putting it in a parent class that extends fragment and then have each Fragment inherit from that class? Is this good android app design or is there a better idea I haven't thought of?

Should I put the logic in my MainActivity since it controls all my Fragments?

Comment: Inheriting is the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a class which inherits from `Fragment`, put all the shared logic in that, and then derive your final classes from it.